# Cannot add vector asset as icon in Android Studio

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, android-icons, google-material-icons

I am writing code in Android Studio to make a basic calculator as a part of my beginner's program. I want to add **backspace** icon into my application button. But when I try to do so, I get an error and the icon is not displayed on the button. I have attached screenshots of the problem and the part of code where I am facing the issue.

Also I noticed one thing that the Vector Asset I add doesn't have **ic_** at it's beginning whereas other icons have **ic_** at beginning of their name.

```
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLdjL.png) Complete Screen where I am facing issue
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SjLV.png) The error 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKdcT.png) Icon code 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWv8x.png) My 'Themes' code
```

I tried to solve the problem by going to **C:\Users\....\svd\icons\material** and deleted the icon_manifest.txt file as it was suggested in many of the answers but, it did not help.

Comment: hmm fill color in the xml seems to be white - perhaps icon has just blended with white background!

Comment: how about trying this line in the layout xml materialbutton? ```app:backgroundTint="#000"```